# UInavigationcontroller Global Alert Message (like WhatsApp incoming message)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, alert

Am building an Application (Forum) and I have an UINavigationController. I want to display an alert message in whatever UIViewController the user is. I have really no idea how i should do it.

Thx a lot for your help.

Here some examples of what i want to do:
and here is the sample [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this view to the `keyWindow`, and bring it to the front.
Or you can make your alertView as a UIWindow, by this way, you can show it anywhere.

```
static UIWindow *_sharedNavigationBarAlertView = nil;
+ (UIWindow *)sharedNavigationBarAlertView
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedNavigationBarAlertView = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _sharedNavigationBarAlertView.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0;
        _sharedNavigationBarAlertView.hidden = YES;
        // add other views...
    });
    return _sharedNavigationBarAlertView;
}

+ (void)showWithInformation:(id)info
{
    // [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].imageView.image = ...;
    // [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].titleLabel.text = @"";
    // [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].detailLabel.text = @"";
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    frame.size.height = 44.0;
    [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].frame = frame;
    [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].hidden = NO;
}
+ (void)hide
{
    [self sharedNavigationBarAlertView].hidden = YES;
}

// To release the shared alert window, just set it to nil
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Exact what I was searching

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can add subviews to it. And you can access it via the `navigationController` property on any of the view controllers or from wherever you have the `UINavigationController` retained. Just add your notification subview and remove it after a delay.

Comment: Okey Thx! But where should I add the subview if I don't show the UINavigationBar?

Comment: You could add it as a subview of the navigation controllers view and ensure that it's the front subview.